# Creating a new row from the combination of two character type rows in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a much larger version of the following data set.

```
mydata <- data.frame("C1" = c("EB", "L", 1, 2, 3) ,
                            "C2" = c("WB", "T", 4, 5, 6),
                            "C3" = c("NB", "R", 7, 8, 9),
                            "C4" = c("SB", "Total", 12, 15, 18),
                            "C5" = c("", "L",1, 2, 3),
                            "C6" = c("", "TR", 4, 5, 6),
                            "C7" = c("", "Total", 5, 7, 9),
                            "C8" = c("", "L",1, 2, 3),
                            "C9" = c("", "R", 4, 5, 6),
                            "C10" = c("", "Total", 5, 7, 9),
                            "C11" = c("", "L",1, 2, 3),
                            "C12" = c("", "TR", 4, 5, 6),
                            "C13" = c("", "Total", 5, 7, 9), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

> mydata
  C1 C2 C3    C4 C5 C6    C7 C8 C9   C10 C11 C12   C13
1 EB WB NB    SB                                      
2  L  T  R Total  L TR Total  L  R Total   L  TR Total
3  1  4  7    12  1  4     5  1  4     5   1   4     5
4  2  5  8    15  2  5     7  2  5     7   2   5     7
5  3  6  9    18  3  6     9  3  6     9   3   6     9
```

I want a combination of the first two rows so the resulting data set will look something like this

```
    > myresult
   C1  C2  C3      C4  C5   C6      C7  C8  C9     C10 C11  C12     C13
1 EBL EBT EBR EBTotal WBL WBTR WBTotal NBL NBR NBTotal SBL SBTR SBTotal
2   1   4   7      12   1    4       5   1   4       5   1    4       5
3   2   5   8      15   2    5       7   2   5       7   2    5       7
4   3   6   9      18   3    6       9   3   6       9   3    6       9
```

Basically, I want to keep the rest of the data frame as it is.

Please note: this is a situation from a very large data set with 1,000 records and 18 cols. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Update:
I've tried

```
mydata[1,]= paste0(rep(mydata[1,], each = length(mydata[2,])), mydata[2,])
```

but this just repeats one value from the first row

```
C1  C2  C3      C4  C5   C6      C7  C8  C9     C10 C11  C12     C13
1 EBL EBT EBR EBTotal EBL EBTR EBTotal EBL EBR EBTotal EBL EBTR EBTotal
2   L   T   R   Total   L   TR   Total   L   R   Total   L   TR   Total
3   1   4   7      12   1    4       5   1   4       5   1    4       5
4   2   5   8      15   2    5       7   2   5       7   2    5       7
5   3   6   9      18   3    6       9   3   6       9   3    6       9
```

Comment: In the desired output, that first row looks a lot like column headers.  Do you want the column headers to be record 1, or would you prefer to make the column headers real column headers in the dataframe?

Comment: I plan to turn the new row into column headers later. Thanks!

Comment: You are storing character strings like `"EBL"` and numbers in the same column, which will force all the numbers to be characters too. Is that what you are expecting?

Comment: The data is being extracted from a website so it's pretty messed up. I'm trying to make it more organized. The plan is to turn the new row into column headers and then turn the character values into numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the data it looks like you want to paste the first row combination with second row till the value `"Total"` comes in second row. We can extract first and second row separately, `split` them based on occurrence of `"Total"` and paste them with `first_row` to get new values.

```
first_row <- mydata[1, ]
first_row <- first_row[first_row != ""]
second_row <- as.character(mydata[2, ])
mydata[1, ] <- unlist(Map(paste0,first_row, split(second_row, 
                c(0, cumsum(second_row == "Total")[-length(second_row)]))))
mydata <- mydata[-2, ] 

mydata
#   C1  C2  C3      C4  C5   C6      C7  C8  C9     C10 C11  C12     C13
#1 EBL EBT EBR EBTotal WBL WBTR WBTotal NBL NBR NBTotal SBL SBTR SBTotal
#3   1   4   7      12   1    4       5   1   4       5   1    4       5
#4   2   5   8      15   2    5       7   2   5       7   2    5       7
#5   3   6   9      18   3    6       9   3   6       9   3    6       9
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to repeat 'EB' four times and the others only three times. I think now it is correct:

```
colnames(mydata) <- paste0(c(rep(mydata[1,1], 4), rep(mydata[1, 2:4], each = 3)), mydata[2,])
mydata2 <- apply(mydata[-c(1:2),], 2, as.numeric)

> mydata2
     EBL EBT EBR EBTotal WBL WBTR WBTotal NBL NBR NBTotal SBL SBTR SBTotal
[1,]   1   4   7      12   1    4       5   1   4       5   1    4       5
[2,]   2   5   8      15   2    5       7   2   5       7   2    5       7
[3,]   3   6   9      18   3    6       9   3   6       9   3    6       9
```

Comment: Thanks! But this basically combines the two rows. What I wanted it was to concatenate "EB" with "L" , "T", "R" and "Total" (in this order) and then start to concatenate "WB" with "L" through "Total" and so on. The idea is- the combination/concatenation command will understand that it has to start from "L" and end at "Total" and then start taking new values from first row. Sorry, if I wasn't clear before. This is my first time posting question here.

Comment: Oh, now I see what you wanted to do. Answer edited.

Comment: Thank you! This helps in case of small dataset. But I want to avoid having to look at how many times EB has to be repeated, how many times WB has to be repeated and so on. Something like expand.grid but I don't want all the combinations. I've tried something else..didn't get the result I wanted. Please check the update of my question.